# Can apache superset be used to embed charts and dashboards into public website where authentication is not required for users?

Tags: apache-superset

Can apache superset be used to embed charts and dashboards into a public website where authentication is not required for users? If yes, what are the security implications? Are there any better strategies or solutions someone has implemented?

Answer (score 2):

##### Before Superset 1.5.0

Dashboard can be embedded with the usage of `iframe` tag.

```
<iframe src="dashboardLink?standalone=true" />
```

To avoid Superset authorization `PUBLIC_ROLE_LIKE = 'Gamma'` must be set in superset_config.py, which will make all dashboards readable without authorization. This approach does not cover the need where access to the dashboards should be provided only through your application.

If this approach does not fit due to security reasons a custom authentication layer can be implemented as described in the following [article](https://sairamkrish.medium.com/apache-superset-custom-authentication-and-integrate-with-other-micro-services-8217956273c1).

##### Starting from Superset 1.5.0

Now embedding can be done with the usage of [Embedded SDK](https://www.npmjs.com/package/@superset-ui/embedded-sdk). This provides possibility to embed dashboards through your application. This means that you will be able to provide access to the dashboards via your own authorization flow.

Please note that the given feature is still in Alpha and several breaking changes are coming.

See more: https://github.com/apache/superset/issues/17187

Answer (score 1):

You can embed charts using IFrames.
For security you can set the Public role to have the same characteristics as Gamma role in the **superset_config.py** file,  PUBLIC_ROLE_LIKE = Gamma
This only grants view access to charts and dashboards.

Comment: Thank you for the response @Lenin. But I dont want some one to be able to just copy the iframe src url and use it to embed it other websites or access it out side of our website. Is there a way to restrict the chart to be available only through our website. And I dont want to present the user with a superset login screen as well.  Is there a way to achieve what I am looking for?

Answer (score 0):

You can restrict superset to **ONLY** allow dashboards to embed to certain sites (when you enable embedding you can specify the URL(s) of the site(s) you want to allow embedding to.

If you leave it blank, you basically allow anyone who can get the dashboard ID to embed your dashboard, if you specify a URL (has to be a FULL URL), you can restrict it to just one site (or more if  you specify more than one URL).

That is one first layer of security.

Then, you can use CORS to restrict the sites that can access your superset server.

To get embedding to work, you should have set a CORS section in your superset_config.py, there you can define the origins you want to allow to access superset embedding

what has worked for us (on the superset_config.py side) is:

```
    '''
    Dashboard Embedding Stuff
    '''
    FEATURE_FLAGS = {"EMBEDDED_SUPERSET": True,
                     "EMBEDDABLE_CHARTS": True }
    
    SESSION_COOKIE_SAMESITE = None
    WTF_CSRF_ENABLED = False
    TALISMAN_ENABLED = False
    GUEST_ROLE_NAME = "Gamma"
    PUBLIC_ROLE_LIKE = "Gamma"
    
    CORS_OPTIONS = {
      'supports_credentials': True,
      'allow_headers': ['*'],
      'resources':['*'],
      'origins': ['*']
    }
    
    '''
    Dashboard Embedding Stuff
    '''
```

You will need to either restrict the access at the dashboard level or on the backend API level if you want any restrictions at all. (OR you could modify the CORS settings up there to restrict who can access superset to suit your purposes.